# How to extract date from datetime value to check for the weekend between two dates?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to check for the weekend between two dates.

row data:

```
29/11/2019  12:45:43  and 30/11/2019  12:45:43
```

My code:

```
Function Check_Weeknd(start_date As Date, end_date As Date) As Boolean

While start_date <> end_date
    start_date = DateAdd("d", 1, start_date)
    If Weekday(start_date) = 7 Then
         Check_Weeknd = True
    End If
 Wend
 End Function
```

Comment: The `Weekday()` function being 7 just tells you that it's a Saturday. Is that your intent? Have you looked into `DateDiff()`? It is not clear what you mean by "check weekend".

Comment: Yes, I need to know if this is weekend. Then I receive the indicator (True)

Comment: So a Sunday doesn't count as being on the weekend?

Comment: Why? I count that as weekend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Function Check_Weeknd(start_date As Date, end_date As Date) As Boolean
    Dim D As Date
    For D = Int(start_date) To Int(end_date)
        If Weekday(D) = vbSaturday Or _
            Weekday(D) = vbSunday Then
                Check_Weeknd = True
                Exit Function
        End If
    Next D
 End Function
```

I added the `Int` function to show how to get rid of the Time, but it's not necessary in this function, as `Weekday` only operates on the date portion.

Perhaps, a bit better:  no `Int` function and the second date entry is optional, so you can test a single date if you need to:

```
Function Check_Weeknd(start_date As Date, Optional end_date As Date) As Boolean
    Dim D As Date
    If end_date = 0 Then end_date = start_date
    For D = start_date To end_date
        If Weekday(D) = vbSaturday Or _
            Weekday(D) = vbSunday Then
                Check_Weeknd = True
                Exit Function
        End If
    Next D
 End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the loop with something like so.

```
Function check_weekend(dtStart As Date, dtEnd As Date) As Boolean

check_weekend = DateDiff("d", dtStart, dtEnd) - _
                WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(dtStart, dtEnd) > 0

End Function
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this logic. Can you explain?

Comment: @Bimka09 Google and learn it, it's two excel functions `DateDiff` and `NetworkDays`

Comment: I know about it but it isn't what i was looking for

Comment: It checks whether the working days `networkdays` between two dates subtracted from the actual number `datediff` of days is greater than 0 `>0`